# Excel: How to get every N-number of cells as a group, move them into their own column until all groups are in their own column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 100,000+ cells in a single row with different values. They are in groups of 101 cells each. Each group of 100 cells has a header cell before the 100 cells that has a value of "Set # N-number".

I would like to know if there is a way to grab every group of 101 cells, cut them (header included), and paste them into their own column until I've cycled through all 1000 groups of 101 cells, starting at the 101st row.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample about your problem, for example I want to transform column A data to each columns, I enter the A1-A20 for the first column and A21- A42 for the second column etc., replace **A** to **=A**:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. You've saved me weeks worth of work and also days worth of frustration in searching for a way to do this.